Singleton object in foregroundservice not working properly
I'm trying to access the variables of an already saved singleton object in main.dart, but it's not working properly. I'm sure it's already been initialized, but when I try to access it, it says it's an uninitialized variable.
I already have sleepDataBloc.startSleepTime(); in mainscreen.dart; Because I declared it like this, the time at the time of declaration should be saved, but in the code I wrote, it says that startSleep is not initialized. Of course, I checked the already saved values ​​in mainscreen.dart through the log.
void startCallback() {
  FlutterForegroundTask.setTaskHandler(MyTaskHandler());
}

void main() {
  widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterForegroundTask.initCommunicationPort();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}


class MyTaskHandler extends TaskHandler {
  SleepDataBloc sleepDataBloc = SleepDataBloc();

  @override
  void onStart(DateTime timestamp) {
  }

  @override
  void onRepeatEvent(DateTime timestamp) {
    sleepDataBloc.saveSleepBackupData(100);
  }

  @override
  void onDestroy(DateTime timestamp) {
    print('foreground service end');
  }
  void onNotificationPressed() {
    FlutterForegroundTask.launchApp('/');
    print('onNotificationPressed');
  }
}

class SleepDataBloc {

  static final SleepDataBloc _instance = SleepDataBloc._internal();
  factory SleepDataBloc() => _instance;

  SleepDataBloc._internal() {
    _initialize();
  }
  late DateTime startSleep;
  void startSleepTime() {
    startSleep = DateTime.now();
  }
}


Based on a cursory scan of the pub docs, it looks like the ForegroundService does not share memory with the main isolate, similar to how a second isolate works.  In that case, you must arrange to send the value back from the foregroundservice to the main UI using sendDataToMain.  (And the API docs confirm that this is an Isolate, yes.)
